# assign typeahead.js array elements to variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I have this typeahead tied to an `<input>` box and it works fine.  I send a request off to the server which gives back an array with 3 elements.  The dropdown box displays, and `displayKey` tells the input box what to display back out to the user.

The thing is, I can grab the value that the user has selected after the fact using

`var a = $('#inputBox').val();` or something, but I need ALL THREE array elements `(partNumber, mfr, title)` that are returned as separate variables, and I'm not sure where in this function I can assign those.

```
// bloodhound
var partsList = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: 'pSearch.php?p=%QUERY',                
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function (partsList) {        
            return $.map(partsList, function (itemNumber) {            
                return {
                    partNumber:   itemNumber.pn,
                    mfr:          itemNumber.mfr,
                    title:        itemNumber.neda                   
                };
            });
        }
    }
});


partsList.initialize();
// typeahead
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'partNumber',    
    limit: 9,
    source: partsList.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<div><strong>{{partNumber}}</strong> > <div class='subtitle'>{{mfr}} > {{title}}</div></div>")
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched around and found a solution to this using `.on('typeahead:selected'`

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'partNumber',    
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<div><strong>{{partNumber}}</strong> > <div class='mfr_suggestion'>{{mfr}} > {{neda}}</div></div>")
    },    
    source: partsList.ttAdapter(),
    limit: 9}).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {    
    console.log(datum.partNumber);
    console.log(datum.mfr);
    console.log(datum.title);
});
```

The 3 variables that are originally passed from bloodhound can be accessed by name using the `datum.[name]` convention.